# AngularJS query works with http, but not work with resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I try to use many answers about that but they did not work.

I am am using an api to get json data with AngularJS.

I can get data with $http and bind it to front end. But i can not get same data with $resource.

When i try to get data with ngResource ($resource) , it gives error like that :

Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

For example, i use this project and you can check the project from here : https://github.com/okproject/AngularGetPost

Can you help me please ?

Result data like :

```
{
geonames: [
{
continent: "EU",
capital: "Andorra la Vella",
languages: "ca",
geonameId: 3041565,
south: 42.42849259876837,
isoAlpha3: "AND",
north: 42.65604389629997,
fipsCode: "AN",
population: "84000",
east: 1.7865427778319827,
isoNumeric: "020",
areaInSqKm: "468.0",
countryCode: "AD",
west: 1.4071867141112762,
countryName: "Andorra",
continentName: "Europe",
currencyCode: "EUR"
},
{
continent: "AS",
capital: "Abu Dhabi",
languages: "ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur",
geonameId: 290557,
south: 22.633329391479492,
isoAlpha3: "ARE",
north: 26.08415985107422,
fipsCode: "AE",
population: "4975593",
east: 56.38166046142578,
isoNumeric: "784",
areaInSqKm: "82880.0",
countryCode: "AE",
west: 51.58332824707031,
countryName: "United Arab Emirates",
continentName: "Asia",
currencyCode: "AED"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried, and got it working, the thing is the call you are making is returning an object, not an array:

```
{"geonames":[{"continent":"EU","capital":"Andorra la Vella","
```

I got it working by changing the resource params (isArray: false)

```
var resource = $resource('http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=okproject', {}, { 'query': { method: 'GET',isArray: false}});
```

By the way I changed as well the username to "okproject" the default account for the rest call was failing as well.

Snapshot of the result:

[image]

In your controller you will have to update the GetEvent callback

```
$scope.callWithResource=function() {
    GeoService.getEvent().then(function (response) {            
        $scope.countries = response.geonames;
    });
};
```

Comment: It is interesting.The problem is , when i use this resource with get and post actions together, it does not work. But when i define resource just for get like your example, it works. Do you know, what is the problem happening, when we use post and get methods together ?

Comment: Just tried var resource = $resource('http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=okproject', { 'post': { method: 'POST' } }, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }); and it still works, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Ouw i found it.As a summary, i have to remove curly braces after url. If i use this, it does not work. Check curly braces after url. var resource=$resource('http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=okproject',{},{'post': {method: 'POST'}}, { 'query': { method: 'GET',isArray: false}});